# GWT gen name of class field

Tags: gwt, java, lang

I know that in GWT the java reflection tools isn't emulated, but is there a way to get name of class field?

Comment: what do you mean "name of class field"?

Comment: class ExampleClass {
    private Integer ImField;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Also due too obfuscating is the field name different than the name in the source code, or even due too optimization could the field be optimized away and not appear in the generated JavaScript.